# Specific application of Fourier Transform

Tags: signal-processing

Let's say I have two frequencies sounding at the same time.

There's a harmonic series above each, right.

I need to know the frequency of the coincidental partial in order to apply a band pass filter around that frequency in real time.

Can this be done?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

if you have two frequencies, then you have two sinus in superposition.

you have two option to extract one of the frequencies:

1. do a fft, then in the output you will get the two frequencies represented as two bins, then    select the bin that represent the frequency you are interested in, (this is time consuming if you are doing the fft especially for this reason).
2. you can also implement an iir (or fir, iir is usually more efficient) band pass filter around the relevant frequency  (if you have only two frequencies a low pass or high pass will be sufficient).